# Computational Complexity of the class of $\Delta_0$ functions (over $V_\omega$)

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

I would like to know where the class of functions whose graph is $\Delta_0$ (over $V_\omega$) fits in the computational complexity hierarchy. Also is there a nice notion of $\Delta_0$-reducibility between subsets of natrual numbers (in analog with either polynomial time reducibility or Turing reducibility)?

References are welcome.